# Haskell - ending part of recursive call early

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that returns to possible lists of animals that can be drawn from a string (without repetition)

ie given

```
dict=["dog","cat","bat","cock","cow","pig","fox",
      "ant","bird","lion","wolf","deer","bear","frog",
      "hen","mole","duck","goat"]
```

should give

```
λ= fnd dict "gtcoaode"
[["dog","cat"],["goat"]]
```

I would like the output to just be maximum numbers of animals that can be drawn from the string in each case:

my code so far is:

```
contains :: String -> String -> Bool
contains x y = length (x \\ y) == (length x - length y)

fnd :: [String] -> String -> [String]
fnd [] _ = [[]]
fnd (x:xs) y
     | y `contain` x = (([x]++) <$> (fnd (x:xs) (y \\ x))) ++ (fnd xs y)
     | otherwise     = scp xs y
```

However this gives:

```
λ= fnd names "gtcoaode"
[["dog","cat"],["dog"],["cat"],["goat"],[]]
(0.01 secs, 2,144,368 bytes)
```

What is the best way to deal with the cases that are repititions

Comment: Can you include the definition of `scp` also?

Comment: Why are `"dog"` and `"cat"` together in one list while `"goat"` is alone in its own list?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `"dog"` and `"cat"` can be made simultaneously with the given letters, so they are grouped together. The function is intended to return lists of animals, and "goat" was a singleton list.

Comment: @B.Mehta Ah, you mean that `"dog"` and `"goat"` can't be made simultaneously because they both have a `g` but there is only one in the input string. Is that correct?

Comment: That's my impression, yes.

Comment: @B.Mehta  was meant to be `fnd`. fixed now

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, you can make a list with "dog","cat" OR one with "goat"

Comment: What would `fnd names "aattcbn"` give? `[[ bat, cat ], [ cat, ant ], [ bat, ant ]]` or something like `[[ bat, cat ], [ ant ]]`? You might want to think about that a bit...

Comment: @monocell in its current state it would give `[["cat","bat"],["cat","ant"],["cat"],["bat","ant"],["bat"],["ant"],[]]` but should give `[["cat","bat"],["cat","ant"],["bat","ant"]]`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to insert each element you find into a `Data.List.Ordered` or a set, rather than append it to the end of a list.  That guarantees uniqueness.  You could also pass the set you’re generating as an accumulating parameter and make the function itself tail-recursive or a fold.

### Update

Since it sounds like you want to solve this specific problem itself, here’s a not-especially-efficient solution to a contrived problem: given a string, make a sorted list of every consecutive pair of letters, with no duplicates.

```
main :: IO ()
main = (print . myNub . digraphs) "banana"

insertSet :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
{- Inserts an element into a set, represented as a sorted list in ascending
 - order.  If an element in the set is already equal to x, x replaces the
 - first such element.
 -}
insertSet x [] = [x]
insertSet x (y:ys) | x == y    = x:ys
                   | x < y     = x:y:ys
                   | otherwise = y:(insertSet x ys)

myNub :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
{- A naïve insertion sort of the input list that removes duplicates (and equiv-
 - alents).
 -}
myNub xs = go [] xs where
  go acc [] = acc
  go acc (y:ys) = go (insertSet y acc) ys

digraphs :: String -> [String]
{- Returns the list of all consecutive pairs of letters in the string.
 -}
digraphs [] = []
digraphs [_] = []
digraphs (x1:x2:xs) = [x1,x2]:(digraphs (x2:xs))
```

Some basic optimizations you could do: sort the list in O(n log n) time and then scan it for duplicates in O(n) time; make the `acc` parameter of `insertSet` strict; use the `foldl'` higher-order function; use the function from `Data.List.Ordered`.

You’re better off using a different data structure, though.  In this case, since there are a small number of possible results (`["cat"]`, `["dog"]`, `["cat","dog"]`, etc.) that can be included or excluded by counting the occurrences of letters, you could simply count the number of times each letter occurs in a single pass.

Comment: would you please give an example with accumulator?

Comment: Updated my answer.